# iOS Linen background CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, mobile-safari

Is it possible to customize the linen background shown when you scroll past the end/top of the page in mobile safari via CSS/Javascript?

I know it can be done via Obj C, but Im not developing an application, Im developing a website in native mobile safari for the web.

Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to customize this background.

The only workaround I can think of is to disable scrolling by `preventDefault()`-ing the various touch events on `window` and implement your own scrolling.

Comment: I can implement my own scrolling, but I'd rather not, so I'll leave it at that since its natively impossible, thanks for the quick reply =)